# Why does my for loop return 'undefined' as the last element of a string

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop

I was trying to reverse a string using a for loop. The approach I took was to iterate backwards through the entire string, get each separate character of a string in a descending order and then concatenate the reversed characters together in a new, reversed string.
However, I encountered a small issue - the string did reverse, but 'undefined' was concatenated at the start.

What am I doing wrong and why this is hapenning? Many thanks for help in advance.

Please, see the code snippet and console for details.

```js
const string = "A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
let newStr = "";

for (let i = string.length; i >= 0; i--) {
  let char = string[i];
  newStr += char;
}

console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: Your `i` starts at `string.length`, consider what happens when you try and access `string[string.length]` from your string

Comment: The following makes it simple to reverse. ```string.split("").reverse().join("")```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because array starts from 0 and latest element is accessible by `length-1` so the `array[length]` is equal to writing `array[999999]`

```js
const string = "A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
let newStr = "";

for (let i = string.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  let char = string[i];
  newStr += char;
}

console.log(newStr);
//alternative way
console.log(string.split('').reverse().join(''));
```

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. I actually knew how to get the last element in an array/string, just couldn't put 2 and 2 together.

Comment: @superpav cool, I'd also added an alternative way FYI too

Answer (score 0):

You should start from `string.length - 1` since `string[string.length]` is trying to refer an element out of bounds of the array, hence, evaluates to `undefined`

```js
const string = "A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
let newStr = "";

for (let i = string.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  let char = string[i];
  newStr += char;
}

console.log(newStr);
```